# Migrate Eclipse project to Gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to move my current android project to a Gradle project, so here what I've done so far:

1. add gradle to eclipse
2. generation of `build.gradle` file
3. create `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable in Windows 7
4. at the root of my project in command prompt: `gradlew build`

So now, I've got a new folders structure in my project:

[image: Gradle project]

It's my first time with gradle, I guess I missed something and I would like to know if to finish this migration I have to delete the src and res directories (in blue) ? For me I just have to get a new structure of folders after the generation of gradleview build..
And if what I've generated looks like to a gradle project ?

Comment: In my case migrating to Android Studio with Gradle from Eclipse ADT was quite straight forward. I simply used the "import" in Android Studio and everything was working fine. However I did NOT export from Eclipse. I imported from Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project structure does not fit to android studios structure you can add your folders to the source set in the gradle file of your app.
So your android studio will match the correct folders

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        // manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        // java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'build/generated/source/apt/${variant.dirName}']
        // resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
        // res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        // assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
    }
}
```

as copied from [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle)

Comment: I didn't find others solutions at the moment so I followed your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was typo: use `gradlew build` or `gradle build`

You can keep Eclipse folder structure and configure it in `build.gradle`

Yet I would recommend to move source into `src/main/java`.
Eclipse would be quite OK with that.

http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/Make-Android-Eclipse-project-ready-for-Android-Studio